# Pass by Reference a static field in PHP

Tags: php, closures, pass-by-reference, static-members

```
self::$ancestors = array();
self::ancestors_each($arFields['ID'], function($section_id) use(self::&$ancestors) {
            $ancestors[$section_id] = true;
        });
```

I need to collect some stuff with a closure into a static field array. So I need to pass it into a closure by reference. How do I achieve that?